# How to combine Basic Strategies to a winning-system

Tags: chess-variants, online-chess

Suppose one want to have a strategy so one can win over a "normal/average" chess-player. I was thinking that there was a set of strategies which could be combined so that  one could memorize it? Say the opening and the middle game. Then one could always win over a "non experienced" chess-player.

Comment: There is no such thing as "always win" in chess.

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematically proven winning strategy as can be found for solved games such as tic-tac-toe or connect four?

Comment: I don't think it's that bad of a question. If they existed, I'd sure like to know about them!

Answer (score 6):

That's not how chess works.

Chess has [too many possibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number) for a "one size fits all"-strategy or set of strategies that you could learn by heart.

At the risk of repeating myself: Learning chess is like learning a language. It's kind of hard to learn a set of sentences that allow you to win any debate against an average debater.

Instead, "understanding" is the key. Languages and chess have to be learnt the hard way: Maybe some rote learning can be beneficial, but mostly you'll need lots of practice and exposure to "good chess"/correct language until you have developed an intuition about sentence structures/connotations/positions/tactics etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a knockout strategy that works, if you do all these things:

1. Move your pieces off the back row as soon as practical. Try to move at least one knight and one bishop before moving the queen, however.
2. Per #1, don't move the same piece twice in the beginning of the game without a good reason.
3. Castle as soon as you can.
4. Occupy the center of the board with your pawns and pieces. The center of the board allows you to attack either side, and constricts your opponent.
5. If you can take your opponent's pieces, do so. Material superiority is helpful. Be careful about traps, however.
6. After you choose your move, use your mind to visualize the board as it will be in the next move or two.  If you don't like what you "see", choose a different move.

Comment: I think the problematic part is hidden in 'as soon as practical', 'without a good reason','as soon as you can', 'If you can' and the complete final sentence: 'If you don't like what you "see", choose a different move.' If you have mastered these minor details, it is a knockout strategy indeed. Magnus Carlsen doesn't do it any different.

Comment: "Magnus Carlsen doesn't do it any different." Thanks @BlindKungFuMaster. That was my point. But the OP doesn't have to master them, he just as to do a little better than his opponent. If he applies those 6 easy steps more often than not, he's gonna start cutting some heads. It will take practice of course.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you call average/normal and just how good you are.

The only strategy guaranteed to work is just to keep making better moves than they do.

If you are at all decent then you should be able to beat a non experienced player just by playing well.

You should be more concerned about what a very experienced or very good player is going to do to you.

I would say what you need more than a magic strategy is to study the basics of tactics, end games, pawn structure, and learn one opening well.